# How can i optimise this backwards related objects query? (django)

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given the code below, I want to get the latest 6 blogs using the backwards queries described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)).  For each of these blogs I need to get their associated photos.

There are 7 queries run to accomplish this and it seems like a lot.  Is there any way I can optimise it?

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="150")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published', null=True, blank=True)

class BlogImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    parent_blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)

items = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:6]

my_list = list()
for item in items:
    tup = (item,item.blogimage_set.all())
    my_list.append(tup)

return  render(request, 'template.html',{'items': my_list})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prefetch_related` to prefetch any items accross a multi-valued relation (many-to-many or reverse foreign-key relations).

```
items = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date').prefetch_related('blogimage_set')[:6]
```

This will reduce the amount of queries to 2, 1 for all the blogs, and 1 for all images related to any of the blogs.

([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related))